# Python - User input as an argument in a function?

Tags: python

Say I define a function with a parameter of (x).
Is it possible to use input provided by the user, saved into a variable (x), that is used as the parameter of the function?

Comment: Can you provide an example of usage please?

Comment: marked as duplicate, ping me if you heavily edit your question I'll reopen otherwise you have you answer in the link.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python2 try `raw_input` method:

```
x=raw_input("please input a string")
```

Or in Python3 try `input` method:

```
x=input("please input a string")
```

Comment: I don't _think_ this is what the OP wanted, but maybe I'm wrong. Also, please at least provide a link to usage instruction, or add an explanation your self.

Comment: if that's what the user wants, then the duplicate link is enough.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That's right